# Eloquent - change return format

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this very simple line :

```
$user["emails"] = $user->emails()->get(array('email'));
```

When returned in JSON it gives an array of objects

```
0 : {email: "aaa@gmail.com", pivot: {user_id: "1", email_id: "1", confirm: "1"}},
1 : {email: "bbb@gmail.com", pivot: {user_id: "1", email_id: "2", confirm: "0"}},
2 : {email: "ccc@jb.com", pivot: {user_id: "1", email_id: "3", confirm: "0"}}
```

If needed, the user-emails() function :

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email', 'user_email')->withPivot('confirm');
```

I would like the returned data to be simpler. Like so :

```
0 : "aaa@gmail.com",
1 : "bbb@gmail.com",
2 : "ccc@jb.com"
```

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `pluck()`.

```
$user['emails'] = $user->emails()->pluck('email');
```

This will return an array of emails in the manner you requested.
You can find information about this in the 'Retrieving A List of Column Values' subsection at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: When trying your solution, only the first email is sent. There is no array, only "aaa@gmail.com"

Comment: According to the documentation, this will return an array of the email column for all returned results.

Comment: `pluck()` will return a Collection, if you need the array use `->pluck('email')->all()`. See http://devdocs.io/laravel~5.3/api/5.3/illuminate/database/eloquent/builder#method_pluck for more info.

Comment: Hello guys, and thanks for answering. When I try to `->pluck('email')->all()` I have a `FatalErrorException : Call to a member function all() on string`. I realize that according to the documentation you are right, but I don't get why it doesn't work for my case.

Comment: @ollieread Yes ! I assume that's the issue... I will upgrade Laravel immediately, thanks !